# How to call LESS Mixins outside of CSS Classes?

Tags: less

Although **LESS is a Preprocessor**, how can I do this

```
@ltr: ltr;
@rtl: rtl;
@dir: @rtl;

.SetTypeFaceVariables when (@dir = @ltr) {
    @headType: 'Segoe UI_';
}
.SetTypeFaceVariables when (@dir = @rtl) {
    @headType: Tahoma;
}

.SetTypeFaceVariables();  // Error is here, we cannot call Mixins here like this

h1{
   font-family: @headType;
}
```

How can I define **@headType** variable in different direction?

---

Thanks to @seven-phases-max you can find the **[Demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/JImdF)**

Comment: did u try calling the `mixin` within `h1` tag?

Comment: > we cannot call Mixins here like this - In fact we can. What Less compiler do you use?

Comment: @seven-phases-max I'm using **Mindscape Web WorkBech** it is a **Visual Studio extension**

Comment: @seven-phases-max this is the Mindscape website http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's already mentioned in comments your example compiles fine with Less version 1.5.0 and higher. Most likely your IDE ships with some outdated version of the Less compiler (1.4.2? 1.3.3?). Never mind, you need just a tiny fix to make the code to be compatible with ancient Less versions (down to 1.3.2):

```
@ltr: ltr;
@rtl: rtl;
@dir: @ltr;

// the magic is in parens:
.SetTypeFaceVariables() when (@dir = @ltr) {
    @headType: 'Segoe UI_';
}
.SetTypeFaceVariables() when (@dir = @rtl) {
    @headType: Tahoma;
}

.SetTypeFaceVariables(); 

h1 {
   font-family: @headType;
}
```

Comment: In the code, I can not see any difference between your code and mine, how did you made it compatible with older LESS version? is it the same code or you changed it?

Comment: Codepen demo uses Less 1.5.0. And the code of the answer has its comment near the key difference.